# Orientation is working but data size is not fit on the screen. Pasted code is the function of orientation

Tags: javascript, android, highcharts

Orientation is working but data size is not fit on the screen.

```
function doOnOrientationChange()
    {
    var hhei= 0;
    switch(window.orientation)
    {
    case -90:
    hhei= ($(document).height())*2.0/4;


     alert("-90:"+hhei);
    chartcreator(ticks,s1,s2,legendEquipments,hhei);
    break;
    case 90:
    hhei= ($(document).height())*2.0/4;
     alert("90:"+hhei);
    chartcreator(ticks,s1,s2,legendEquipments,hhei);
    break;
    case 0:
    hhei= ($(document).height())*2.0/4;
     alert("0:"+hhei);
    chartcreator(ticks,s1,s2,legendEquipments,hhei);
    break;
    case 180:
    hhei= ($(document).height())*2.0/4;
    alert("180:"+hhei);
    chartcreator(ticks,s1,s2,legendEquipments,hhei);
    break;
    }
    }
```

90' shows vertical and 180' shows the horizaontal layout. I dont know how to fix it

Comment: i don't understand where the problem is?

Comment: The chart shows outside the layout and it has small size when i increased 2.0/4 to 3.1 or someother it displays outside the layout.

Comment: all your cases do the same thing, what is even the point of the switch, here?